# Vertical alignning a span within a Panel Header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In a panel accordion ('m using bootstrap 3.3.7 with the application), within the panel header I need to show some content and a box in the right side corner. What i want is to align the box item to the right side corner middle position. How can i do this.

This is what i tried so far.

```css
.mainBox {
  background-color: #00c0ef !important;
  color: white !important;
  padding: 5px 10px !important;
}

.lineBox {
  font-size: small;
  white-space: pre-line;
  align-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.deleteBox {
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 5px, 5px;
  color: white !important;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel-group accordion-Queue" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading mainBox" role="tab" id="headingOne">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                           
                            Collapsible Group Item #1
                           
                            
                            <span class="deleteBox pull-right">
                                <span>TAB DRAFT</span> 
                            </span>

                            <span class="lineBox">
                                Collapsible Group Item #1
                            </span>
                        </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid.</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood your question, you want to vertically align the "TAB DRAFT" box on the right.

If you move the element out of the h4 tag it's easier to achieve this by using flex on your .mainBox class.

Also worth noting, vertical-align only works on inline elements.

```css
.mainBox {
  background-color: #00c0ef !important;
  color: white !important;
  padding: 5px 10px !important;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.lineBox {
  font-size: small;
  white-space: pre-line;
  align-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.deleteBox {
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white !important;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <div class="col-md-12">
<div class="panel-group accordion-Queue" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading mainBox" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          <span>
            Collapsible Group Item #1
          </span>
          <span class="lineBox">
            Collapsible Group Item #1
          </span>
        </a>
      </h4>

      <span class="deleteBox pull-right">
        <span>TAB DRAFT</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid.</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thax exactly what i wanted.